# Open numeric keypad android without edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want to open numeric keyboard without having `edittext` in my entire layout.
So far i am able to display the keyboard. But i am not able to change the type to numeric keyboard.

Here is the code which is working for now, but i want to switch the keyboard to Numeric keypad.

```
requestFocus();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(context, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }, 300);
```

This is all over a view which i request focus then when its clicked i want to show  numeric keypad.

Comment: if you dont waana edittext and want to open keypad then where you want to display typed text?..prgrameticall you can do it setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);..or you can set android:inputType="phone"

Comment: I will show dots to user and store number in memory :)

Comment: where you will show that dots??and to show dots use android:inputType="password"

Comment: Why are you getting confused i have frame layout or other layout where i will show anything just to indicate the user that something is happened. And that rawinput is of to no use as i said i dont have any TextView or EditText :)

Comment: then you have to give description of layouts in question too

Comment: I would try putting an EditText with visibility gone. Worth a try!

Comment: Yes then if you can read clearly "This is all over a view which i request focus then when its clicked i want to show numeric keypad."

Comment: @shiladitya i thought same at first go but was searching for option without EditText and yes it works thank you :)

Comment: @shiladitya but a little glitch is observed when setting it to gone as you know i dont that edit text visible in layout

Answer (score 0):

set backGround of editText transparent.

```
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"/>
```

set input type programatically.

```
editText.setRawInputType(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Very similar to Tushar's answer, I recommend doing the following.

In your layout add an EditText that is so small it's not visible.
Note that I placed the EditText within a ConstraintLayout.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="0.1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
```

Using Kotlin I created an extension to show the keyboard.

`ViewExtensions.kt`

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager


fun View.showKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

Then when I want to show the keyboard I do the following.

```
myEditText.requestFocus()
myEditText.showKeyboard()
```

If you were using Java you would just pass your EditText into the `showSoftInput()` method.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Then if you're using ButterKnife you could observe the text with a listener like this.

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.myEditText)
fun textChanged(text: CharSequence) {
    //Add code here
}
```

If you're not using ButterKnife you could simply use
`myEditText.addTextChangedListener(...)`